# Find all files in iphone project

Tags: iphone, file, utilities

I'm curious if there's a way to search for files in the iPhone's directory ( the location is irrelevant).

I am wanting to load in addresses from text files. The thing is additional files may be added and I want to dynamically be able to find the files and load in the data without hardcoding the file names to load in.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&error]
```

It returns an array of NSString objects for each file in the given directory.